# IOS: Create a reusable UI widget that can be used in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, ipad, interface-builder

IOS: Create a reusable UI widget that can be used in Interface Builder?  How do you create an element that can be used in other forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is make a subclass of your object, let's say `UIButton` for instance.

### Custom Object:

```
@interface MyCustomButton : UIButton 
{
    UIColor *tintColor;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIColor *tintColor;
@end
```

### Your Class:

```
#import "MyCustomButton.h"
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet MyCustomButton *myButton;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) MyCustomButton *myButton;
@end
```

Now in interface Builder, add a `UIBUtton` and you can connect it to your custom **myButton**.

Comment: Can I use a custom .xib file for that widget?  Let's say I wanted to use custom styling on the table?  Or add an extra button to it?

Comment: What does one do so that the tint colour is always white and the background colour of the button is always black for example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `Interface Builder` instead of `UIBuilder` and something close to what you are looking for is here

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/custom-views-in-interface-builder-using.html

but it doesn't work on iOS.

Comment: If it doesn't work on IOS how could that be what I'm looking for?

Comment: may be possible in new iOS versions after certain amount of time.